# NextJS button inside Link component

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I wonder how is possible to have button inside NextJS Link component?
When you wrap the button by  and click the button, then it run onClick event and after it redirect to value in href attribute.

How can you just run onClick button event and stop redirecting?

```
<Link href={`./${school.attributes.Slug}/obor/${field.attributes.Code}`}>
  <div className="responsive-table__row">
    <div className="responsive-table__item">50</div>
    <div className="responsive-table__item">40/50</div>
    <div className="responsive-table__item">Test</div>
    <div className="responsive-table__item">
      <button className="responsive-table__button button button--secondary" onClick={() => handleModalOpenerClick(field)}>Show modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</Link>
```

Comment: You can't have a button inside a link - it's invalid html and the browser may change it which could cause you issues.  If you are having it do a separate action to your link, then you should put it outside your link, otherwise change it to a span and style it like a button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your onClick handler to this:

```
onClick={(e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   handleModalOpenerClick(field);
}}
```

and it should work.